# Android SQLiteOpenHelper multithread ad AndroidTestCase support at the same time

Tags: android, multithreading, junit, sqliteopenhelper

I have a SQLiteOpenHelper  that wraps my Database. the SQLiteOpenHelper subclass is implemented as Singleton to avoid MultiTread problems and it seems to work quite well.

The problem is: testing classes that uses the database.

In AndroidTestCase i want to test methods that depends on DB in isolation so i use

`setContext(new RenamingDelegatingContext(getContext(), "test_"));`

and than use the IsolatedContext to get a separate empty instance of the db.

So, the android app need the singleton but Junit need a simple instance.

The only approach i found at the moment is declare SQLiteOpenHelper subclass with two contructors , one static that return the singleton instance and another that return a new instance . Than add to every class that use the db add one constructor to use the singleton an other that use a new instance.
   This approach it is very ugly and error prone , so there is a more logical elegant way to do so?

(ps i'm not using ContentProvider and not interested in so please do not suggest them as solution)

Comment: Let's see: Singleton to avoid MultiThreading problems.  Don't want to use a ContentProvider.  Maybe this will help: https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid

Comment: interesting reading but quite pointless , i know that singletons may be used carefully, i can't use ContentProvider because it is a library (and if you ever used it in a library u know what a'm talking about) if you know some way to use single connection SQLiteOpenHelper in more elegant way i would be glad to learn it

Comment: ContentProviders are, absolutely, not "a library", but they are probably irrelevant, here.  The best way to test code that depends on your OpenHelper is to make it not a singleton.  As Yegge points out, there are many other reasons for not using a singleton.  In fact, (again, as Yegge points out) there is really very little reason *for* using a singleton.  Not my circus, not my monkey, but you might want to consider re-architecting your app so that the OpenHelper doesn't have to be a singleton.

Comment: if you have some app code example in mind with multiple db entry points in mind that don't use the evilish Singleton i will help me a lot

Comment: The general approach is to invert your idea.  In fact, usually called "Inversion of Control".  Objects architected to have their DAO passed to them, on creation (or soon after), are easy to test because they can be handed a mock, instead of the real thing.  This is harder in the Android environment than many places but still quite possible.  Though it is a major re-think, you might even consider Dagger, an Android-friendly IOC framework.